# jquery only insert first row query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of products and each row has an "add to cart button". The script works fine for the first row it inserts the art.code and number of items and returns a response. If I press a different article further down the list, the script does not work. I read somewhere in another question that the id needs to be unique, but I really don't know how to implement that into my script.

---

```
<form method='post' action='search.php'>
 <input type='hidden' id='cartart' name='cartart' value='".$artno."' />
 <input id='cartantal' type='number' name='cartantal'value='".$number."' />
 <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='add'/>
 </form>

<span id='result'></span>
```

and so on...

---

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click( function(){

        var namn = $('#cartart').val();
        var antal = $('#cartantal').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: 'gui_artkod=' + namn + '&gui_antal=' + antal,

            success: function(result){
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
  });
```

---

Comment: you use the same dom id multiple times

Comment: Do you have multiple forms?

Comment: @MrCode yes I use multiple forms

Comment: you can also use jquery.validate library including jquery.form js to validate and submit form, no matter if u have multiple form in one page define all form with unique id and assign appropriate code to each form submission and validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have in your code is you have multiple form with the same ids. Ids should always be unique (that's why it is called ID).

Change all your IDs to class:

```
<form method='post' action='search.php'>
 <input type='hidden' class='cartart' name='cartart' value='".$artno."' />
 <input class='cartantal' type='number' name='cartantal'value='".$number."' />
 <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='add'/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".submit").click( function(){  //use class selector

    var namn = $(this).parent().find('.cartart').val();  //finds the parent of the clicked button  and search for a class called cartart and gets the value 
    var antal = $(this).parent().find('.cartantal').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'gui_artkod=' + namn + '&gui_antal=' + antal,

        success: function(result){
            $("#result").html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I made all the changes that you suggested but it does not seem to work

Comment: this should work check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tbWHp/1/ ... this is just an example.. where i alert the `namn` and `antal` for each product .. and it has correct values....

Comment: many many thanks, there seems to be an error in my mysqli query - it now works perfectly, except for the success returns its value to the first #result, but I'll have a go and try to work it out

Comment: ok.. that means even ur `<div id=result>` is multiple.... u can do the same things, make it a class, select it with the jquery selector....let me now if u face any problem....:)

Answer (score 0):

try using a class instead of a id selector.

Change in HTML : Added a class on the submit button

```
<form method='post' action='search.php'>
 <input type='hidden' id='cartart' name='cartart' value='".$artno."' />
 <input id='cartantal' type='number' name='cartantal'value='".$number."' />
 <input type='submit' name='submit' class='addToShoppingCart' value='add'/>
 </form>
```

Change in Javascript : changed the selector for the submit button.

```
$(function() {
    $(".addToShoppingCart").click( function(){

  ...rest remains same
});
```

You may even make it better by using `.on()`.
Check the documentation for it here : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @frictionlesspulley for some reason I cannot get this to work. It inserts correctly, but it does not return to the same page. instead it goes to search.php